# java android - why images are distorted?

Tags: java, android, png

Just try yourself - put on a layout an ImageView with anyPngYouWant.png and then make a bitmap.xml with

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:src="@drawable/anyPngYouWant"
 />
```

and put in on a same layout..

Why are they different size? I've tried to do many different Images and still in bitmal.xml size of wrap_content differes from source png. I just want them to be same

layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/anyPngYouWant" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/bitmap" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why you need to put it into <bitmap> instead of using it directly, I dont think there is a problem of using the image directly putting it into the ImageView.

Comment: You can't use `.png` files like that `@drawable/anyPngYouWant.png` - **they are not drawable resources yet**.

Comment: because I need to use it in a tileMode. It is distorted in tileMode. But even witout it it is distorted. I can't use design files and I cant make correct layout with all that

Comment: ok, g00dy, how can I use them? I just need to set a png file for tileMode. Help me out

Comment: Check the answer here to see how to properly set an image file to an `imageView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this method, it gets the Bitmap object of the image file and then sets is on the `imageView`:

```
File ifile = new  File(“PATH/anyPngYouWant.png”);
if(ifile.exists()){

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ifile.getAbsolutePath());

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);

}
```

Comment: well, if it's in resourses, why should i need this ? and can I make tiled bitmap out ouf this?

Comment: If it's in the resources, use it like so : `@drawable/anyPngYouWant` without the file extension.

Comment: my mistake, it's without extention, of course ! if you try to do what i've described - you'll see that any of your resourses' png file will be different size if you put it on layout in bitmap.xml . just try to put on a layout 2 same pictures - one as ImageView with anyPngYouWant and another with bitmap.xml with anyPngYouWant set as source. They will be different size !

Comment: It depends from several factors, if the layouts are with fixed size (width and height I mean - this includes fill_parent etc, **except for wrap_content**) you'll see an image with a different size than the original. You see now whay I needed the code + the xml (there might be a clue)? What you can do is to ensure that the original .png image is not distorted itself (open it on the PC), then use my method and set it to an `imageView` with width and height of `wrap_content` and see if it is distorted. Then we'll figure out where the problem is.

Comment: both cases are wrap_content, bitmap.xml is in the question. I've tried that with many different images - bitmap.xml always distorts them although it is set wrap_content on a layout .

Comment: Well, I don't know exactly why you want to use `Bitmap` in the xml and not `imageView`, but anyway here's a suggestion for your problem (you might want to paste the whole xml here) - the `Bitmap` might be a member/child of an enveloping layout, which is limited to the screen size. The `Bitmap` then is wrap_content alright, but one of its dimensions width, height or both might be limited externally by the enveloping layout.

Comment: I've just put layout in the question. I use bitmap because of tileMode, but even without that it distorts image. It is distorted already in eclipse

Comment: Try with `wrap_content` on both width and height of the main `RelativeLayout` for instance?

Comment: isn't that so already? both images are wrap_content . Or you mean to set RelativeLayout as wrap_content? that didn't help

Comment: I meant the last one.

Comment: but it's all wrap_content, I've post it in my question

Comment: This ? - > `<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  ... `

Comment: it doesn't change anything. You may try it yourself with any png file you want - just see it yourself how images change size inside bitmap.xml

Comment: Ok, when i have the time I will try it for sure, it looks interesting.

Comment: don't forget to post it here if u find solution